# Div aparece e some

Tags: jquery, html5

Criei uma div onde tem 2 links, quando a página é carregada, ambos os link estão escondidos e quando eu clicar em "buscar" eles devem aparecer. O detalhe, problema é que elas aparecem e somem! Por que isso pode estar acontecendo?

Segue o código:

```
<input type="submit" name="buscar" id="busca" value="Buscar">

$(document).ready (function(){
    $("#gerar").hide();

    $("#busca").click(function(){
        $("#gerar").show();
    });

});
```

Comment: html:
<input type="submit" name="buscar" id="busca" value="Buscar">

Comment: o `submit` está dentro de um `form`? é possível que após o evento `click` esteja fazendo a requisição do formulário.

Answer (score 3):

Isso é chamado [**FOUC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content), *flash of unstyled content*. Isso quer dizer que o browser mostra o conteudo e só mais tarde vê/lê o script que o esconde, causando um flash momentâneo. E o utilizador vê, temporáriamente, esse conteudo.

A solução, e a maneira correta de fazer é usar CSS para o conteudo não estar visivel quando a página carrega, via CSS. Inline ou no ficheiro CSS.

Deve usar:

```
<div id="gerar" style="display: none;">...conteudo...</div>
```

ou no CSS:

```
#gerar{display: none;}
```

Comment: Oi Sergio,
Simplesmente isso? E tiro o $("#gerar").hide(); do JQ?

Comment: @GustavoSevero exato!

Comment: Sergio, fiz o que me sugeriu <div id="gerar" style="display: none;" e não funcionou.

Comment: @GustavoSevero o que não funcionou? pode descrever o comportamento? o melhor seria partilhar o seu código para podermos ter um exemplo.

Comment: @GustavoSevero estou seguro do que sugeri. Preciso ver o seu código para perceber qual pode ser o problema...

Comment: @GustavoSevero se quiser use este para testar: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln3h53vo/

Comment: <input type="submit" name="buscar" id="busca" value="Buscar">

$(document).ready (function(){
 $("#busca").click(function(){
  $("#gerar").show();
 });
});

Comment: Consegui fazer a div sumir quando é carregada a página, via CSS, mas continua aparecendo e sumindo.
E na verdade é o seguinte, quero que os links que estão dentro dessa div gerar, não apareçam, e quando um busca em uma tabela fora gerada, e mostrar os resultados, dai sim, no final do relatório, os links devem aparecer.

Comment: @GustavoSevero digo novamente: via CSS não deve haver FOUC. Coloque o seu código num jsFiddle que eu ajudo a corrigir.