# Contar elementos e exibir uma quantidade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou precisando exibir um determinado número de elementos do HTML.

Por exemplo:

```
<div class="conteudo">
 <p>Primeiro parágrafo</p>
 <p>Segundo parágrafo</p>
 <p>Terceiro parágrafo</p>
</div>
```

Eu queria exibir somente o primeiro parágrafo dessa div.

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso com javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer assim, usando o selector [gt (greater than)](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) , e todos os p com index superior a `0`, neste caso, ficam com `display: none` (`hide()`):

```js
$('p:gt(0)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conteudo">
 <p>Primeiro parágrafo</p>
 <p>Segundo parágrafo</p>
 <p>Terceiro parágrafo</p>
</div>
```

Com javascript Nativo:

```js
const ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for(var i = 1; i < ps.length; i++) {
 ps[i].style.display = 'none'; 
}
```

```html
<div class="conteudo">
 <p>Primeiro parágrafo</p>
 <p>Segundo parágrafo</p>
 <p>Terceiro parágrafo</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Miguel, sua primeira solução me ajudou e muito. Meio que posso passar um valor como se fosse uma posição de array, eu testei retornando com o primeiro e segundo parágrafo, passando o valor 1 dentro do p:gt()

Comment: @RafaelS.Oiveira , de nada, mas atenção `gt(...)` vai selecionar todos elementos cujo index (começando em 0) seja maior do que aquele que queres. Caso queiras desaparecer só com um elemento fazes com `eq(...)` . E para complementar caso queiras os elementos cujo index seja inferior podes usar `lt(...)`

Answer (score 4):

Podes fazer isso com JavaScript e um seletor CSS assim:

```js
document.querySelector('.conteudo p').style.display = 'block';
```

```css
.conteudo p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteudo">
 <p>Primeiro parágrafo</p>
 <p>Segundo parágrafo</p>
 <p>Terceiro parágrafo</p>
</div>
```

Outra maneira seria somente com CSS assim:

```css
.conteudo p {
  display: none;
}
.conteudo p:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteudo">
 <p>Primeiro parágrafo</p>
 <p>Segundo parágrafo</p>
 <p>Terceiro parágrafo</p>
</div>
```

A segunda alternativa pode ser a melhor visto evitar [FOUC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38008/129), caso seja alternativa usar só CSS.

A terceira alternativa, só mesmo com JavaScript poderia ser assim:

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo p');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  els[i].style.display = i == 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<div class="conteudo">
  <p>Primeiro parágrafo</p>
  <p>Segundo parágrafo</p>
  <p>Terceiro parágrafo</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Valeu Sergio, sua solução é muito boa e útil. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Tem como simular um FOUC... forçar o carregamento primeiro de imagens por exemplo ?

Answer (score 0):

Um jeito diferente dos que já foram postados, com jquery:

```js
$('.conteudo p:first').css({
  color: 'red'  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conteudo">
 <p>Primeiro parágrafo</p>
 <p>Segundo parágrafo</p>
 <p>Terceiro parágrafo</p>
</div>
```